# OpenServer не запускает MySQL

Tags: mysql, openserver

Openserver отказывается запускать MySQL, в конфигурации прописываю
    innodb_force_recovery = 3 но не помогает, Вот логи.

```
2018-10-15 10:47:59  --------------------------------------------
2018-10-15 10:47:59  Start server start-up procedure
2018-10-15 10:47:59  Updating Hosts file
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Updating configuration MySQL-5.6
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Updating configuration of Sendmail
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Updating configuration PHP-5.5
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Updating configuration PHPMyAdmin
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Updating configuration Apache-2.4
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Launch MySQL-5.6
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Launch Apache-2.4
2018-10-15 10:48:00  Checking server status
2018-10-15 10:48:42  Failed to start MySQL-5.6
2018-10-15 10:48:42  Failed to start!
2018-10-15 10:48:42  --------------------------------------------
2018-10-15 10:48:42  Beginning of procedure to stop server
2018-10-15 10:48:42  Stopping system modules
2018-10-15 10:48:43  Turning off a virtual drive
2018-10-15 10:48:43  Server has successfully stopped in 1,235 seconds!
```

Comment: А что в логах MySQL?

Comment: error: Found option without preceding group in config file: 
    d:\programms\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\my.ini at line: 1
    Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

Comment: Битый конфигурационный файл. Исправляйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установил OS на диск C:/ запуситил от имени администратора и всё заработало